# Можно ли употреблять слово "добродетель" в значении "доброхот" (т.е. применительно к человеку)?

Tags: стилистика

Достигнув темного перекрестка, добродетель высадил меня, сообщив, что «весь
проезжающий транспорт идет в столицу», захлопнул дверцу и скрылся.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза, конечно, некорректна. Словом "добродетель" никак не может быть назван человек.

ДОБРОДЕТЕЛЬ, -и; ж. Положительное нравственное качество человека; высокая нравственность, моральная чистота. Ценить, чтить д. Одна из людских добродетелей. Кто-л. полон добродетелей. Женская д.
*(Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова)*

Здесь и "доброхот"-то не слишком подходит, по-моему.

Comment: М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 1 (1932)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)

    А зараз, Александр Анисимович, добродетель мой, верьте слову ― боюсь! [М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 1 (1932)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Comment: Это уж совсем не в тему, это всего-навсего речь героя.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Заменю на "доброжелатель", или "благодетель".

Comment: Если подвёз, то лучше "благодетель" ("материально" помог, делом), если просто посоветовал, то доброжелатель. "Доброхот" обычно употребляется со скептическим оттенком - к людям, склонным навязывать свою помощь незнакомым.

Comment: Доброжелатель не подходит. Согласен с Alex_ander. Или благодетель, или уже просто скажите "водитель".

Comment: *Это уж совсем не в тему, это всего-навсего речь героя* - интересная мысль, а как это сказывается на допустимости использования другим автором в речи другого героя?! Шолохов кабинку занял?! Niemand, самому не смешно?

Comment: behemothus, вы случайно не юрист? Но как бы там ни было, вы чрезвычайно неубедительны. Есть герои и герои. Или у нашего "другого автора" проезжающий транспорт – это сплошь телеги, действие происходит в тьмутаракани, а сам он неграмотный крестьянин? Не говоря уж о том, что это вовсе даже и не "речь героя". Признайтесь уж, что просто спутали добродетель с благодетелем. С кем не бывает, успокойтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не совсем понятен. Доброхот и в одном из значений и добродетель довольно близки по смыслу, вполне взаимозаменяемы. Оба только применительно к человеку и употребляются.

Разница в значениях есть, доброхот - это доброжелатель, не обязательно добродетель, но эта тонкость очень редко оказывается существенной.

Так что если для вас не критична разница между добрым советом и добрым делом, можно оставить в любом варианте, ошибки не будет. Детали ситуации по одной фразе не очень понятны, он что выкинул человека в темном переулке вопреки обещанию? Тогда он не доброхот и не доброжелательно, а совсем наоборот.

В любом случае фраза вполне корректна, если не вдаваться в контекст.

//------------

Опа... Написал - и только потом обнаружил, что у Кузнецова "добродетель" в данном значении отсутствует. Сейчас в другие словари посмотрю. Пока прошу считать мнение предварительным.

//--------
Забавно. Словари такого значения и правда не дают, но оно безусловно существует или некогда существовало.

> М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 1 (1932) [омонимия не снята] Все
>   примеры (1)  А зараз, Александр Анисимович, добродетель мой, верьте
>   слову ― боюсь! [М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 1 (1932)]
>   [омонимия не снята] ←…→

.

> Нина Катерли. Первая ночь (1981)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1)
>       С Антониной тогда так и обошлось ― видно, не стали активистки собирать
>   подписи по второму разу, но про выходку Анны Ивановны ей от
>   кого-то стало известно. ― Тоже мне еще добродетельница нашлась! ―
>   заявила она в тот же вечер. [Нина Катерли. Первая ночь (1981)]
>   [омонимия не снята] ←…→

.

> В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных.
>   Роман в шести частях. Ч. 4 (1864)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры
>   (1)
>      ― Ой, матушки мои, помираю!.. Голубушка вы моя, добродетельница!..
>   Взвою я сейчас, вот, как пес какой, слезами взвою, не выдержу!.. [В.
>   В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. Роман
>   в шести частях. Ч. 4 (1864)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Примеры из нацкорпуса.

Это надо переварить.

(+)=== 13.03.2016

Добавляю два примера для тех, кто уверяет, что он один - да еще почему-то "стилизация".

> К. А. Ливанов. Без Бога (1926-1929) // «Новый Мир», 2002 [омонимия не
>   снята] Все примеры (1) Через тебя, добродетеля нашего, Господь
>   посылает нам свои милости». [К. А. Ливанов. Без Бога (1926-1929) //
>   «Новый Мир», 2002] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

.

> Андрей Ростовский. По законам волчьей стаи (2000) [омонимия не снята]
>   Все примеры (1) Именно он оказался тем самым таинственным
>   добродетелем, бескорыстно помогающим различным благотворительным
>   организациям. [Андрей Ростовский. По законам волчьей стаи (2000)]
>   [омонимия не снята]

И еще.

> Алесь Пашкевич. Сим победиши // «Сибирские огни», 2013   [омонимия не
>   снята] Все примеры (1)
>
> Бью челом моему добродетелю, ― и слегка наклонил перед царем голову.
>   [Алесь Пашкевич. Сим победиши // «Сибирские огни», 2013]
>   [омонимия не снята] ←…→

Вот это больше похоже на стилизацию. Стилизацию историческую, патриархальной речи. Проблема только в том, что по интернету получается, что использование вполне современно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36941/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus-------).

Answer (score 0):

Я где-то когда-то видел, что такие замены приобретают разговорную нормативность при наличии определения. И примеры бегемота это подтверждают.

Comment: Так они уже приобрели? Найдены три (!) примера, причем все три с речью героев (!!), причем два из них с замененным словом (!!!) – и вдруг такие выводы – "разговорная нормативность".

Comment: @Niemand, я призываю Вас подобные формулировки не выносить за наши внутренние разборками. Я достаточно терпелив к Вашим манерам, но не могу Вам обещать, что буду терпеть Ваши передергивания на людях. ***У Morkovkin'а вывод о разговорной нормативности построен не на моих примерах***, примеры (коих конечно не три, а "замена" вполне нормальна) только подтверждают мысль.

Answer (score 0):

Удивительно, какую бурю эмоций вызвал мой простой вопрос: чуть до кулачного боя не дошло. Я уже заменил слово на "благодетель", оно как нельзя лучше подходит здесь по смыслу. "Доброхот" в тексте уже был, а глава называется "Два Сусанина для одного иностранца".

Comment: Бурю вызвал не ваш вопрос, а манеры некоторых местных обитателей спорить, не обозначив предмета сора. Что до вас, то я рад, что вам помогли. Но в таком случае приходится констатировать, что вопрос был поставлен неверно. Если бы вы спросили, на что надо заменить этого "добродетеля", бури бы и не было. Она возникла именно потому, что я отвечал на вопрос именно о законности такого использования слова, а моего оппонентов это интересовало меньше всего. И не стесняйтесь приводить более полный контекст.

Comment: Мне лично интересно только то, что появление этого "добродетеля" в тексте явно не случайно. Если даже два человека употребляют слово так, это уже некая система. А если таких несколько сотен, включая классиков...

Comment: Полный "контекст" - на 214 страницах.:- ) А это предложение пару лет назад было пропущено редактором в общественно-политическую газету.

Comment: Мне кажется что затруднение только лишь в "неснятой омонимии".  Добродетель - человек и добродетель - качество. Инстинкт подсказывает избегать неоднозначности. А вот добродетельница не имеет второго значения, поэтому годится.

Comment: @ddbug, ну знаете... ))) Это, конечно, сильная отговорка. Беда в том, что "доброделигица" точно так же отсутствует в словарях и совершенно очевидно могла образоваться только как женский вариант "добродетеля". Идея о том, что их можно как-то по разному оценивать смогла прийти в голову только Ниманду, теперь вот вам ещё. Но такое обоснования совершенно наивно. Ну нет такого правила в лингвистике, что незаконными автоматически признаются все "нежелательные" омонимы. Плюс тут подмена понятия. Мы говорим о существовании слова. А чтобы что-то запретить, надо для начала признать его существование.